# Sum of sines inequality

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, trigonometric-series

I need to prove the following inequality:
$$\bigg\lvert \sum_{n=1}^{N}\sin(nx)\bigg\rvert \leq \frac{1}{\sin(x/2)}, \, x\neq 2k\pi,k\in \mathbb{Z}$$
No idea where to start. Any tips?

Comment: Hint: $\cos((n-\frac12)x) - \cos((n+\frac12)x) = 2\sin(nx)\sin\frac{x}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

You can start with the factorisation formula (or prove it – it's a standard high-school exercise):
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\sin(nx)=\frac{\sin\frac{(N+1)x}2}{\sin\frac x2}\,\sin \frac{Nx}2.$$

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a good approach, though it doesn't seem that standard to me... how do you go about proving it? I realize that $$\sin(nx)+ \sin((n+1)x) = 2*\sin((2n+1)/2x)\cos(-x/2)$$  But how do I go from here?

Comment: You don't have to do that. Just oberve the absolute values in the  numerator are bounded. As to rthe formula,it results from the geometric series: $ \; 1+\mathrm e^{ix}+\mathrm e^{2ix}+\dots+\mathrm e^{Nix}$, using the closed form and doing some trigonometry, and finally taking the imaginary part.

Answer (score 2):

Hint.

$$
\sum_{n=1}^N \sin(n x)= \mbox{Im}\left[\sum_{n=1}^N e^{i n x }\right] = \mbox{Im}\left[\frac{e^{i(N+1)x}-1}{e^{i x}-1}\right]
$$

Comment: That's very helpful, though I got stuck here...